# Integration- partial fractions - comparing coefficient

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

$$\int \frac{x^2+1}{(x)(x+1)(x-1)}$$

$\frac{x^2+1}{(x)(x+1)(x-1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x+1} + \frac{C}{x-1} $

Through substitution, I found that

$A= -1 $ 
$B= 1$
$C= 1 $

And these are correct .

I'm just curious , so I tried the comparing coefficient method and I got stuck -

$x^2 + 1 = ax^2 - a + bx^2 - bx + cx^2 + cx $

Equation 1 - $A+B+C = 0$

Equation 2 - $ A = -1 $

Equation 3 - $ C - B = 0 $

From 3 - $ C = B $

Sub C=B into 1

$ -1 + B + B = 0 $
$ 2 B = 1 $ 
$B = 0.5$

Where did I go wrong ? Because B should be 1 .

Comment: You made a mistake. $A+B+C=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By comparing coefficient of $x^2$,
$$A+B+C=1$$

rather than

$$A+B+C=0$$